# Is PowerPoint automation from Excel possible with Office Add-Ins?

Tags: vsto, excel-addins

I have a VSTO add-in for Excel that automates PowerPoint, creating new presentation documents and generates slides and other content based on the data in the current Excel workbook. (Using the Primary Interop Assemblies, it creates a new instance of the PowerPoint Application, adds a new Presentation object, Slide objects etc.)

Is it possible for a new Office Add-in to do this so it would run in Excel online, on the Mac, and so on?
It looks like I can get the context of the Office application I'm currently in (e.g. Excel), but I don't see how I can reference the PowerPoint object model, or automate anything outside of Excel itself.

Is this what Microsoft means when it says to create a VSTO add-in

> "...or to extend Office 2013 and Office 2016 **beyond what's possible
> with Office add-ins**. VSTO add-ins run only on the desktop."

rather than building a new JavaScript/HTML Office Add-In?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. Web add-in are on different platforms like Mac where the COM automation technology doesn't exist.

Instead, you may consider using the `Open XML SDK` instead for generating PowerPoint files on the fly from your Excel web add-in. See [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for that - I'm not sure yet, but it looks like I should be able to do everything I want from that SDK. I thought that I might be able to get to an "Office-level" object from the Office context in Office Add-Ins, which would contain the core Excel, PowerPoint, Word, application objects, etc. and be able to work with those. This looks like a viable alternative, although the whole Javascript/React/HTML/Open XML SDK set up does seem more convoluted than straight VSTO or VBA.

Comment: Just thinking, looking at all the sample code on those Open XML SDK pages, they're all in either C# or VB. If I'm using JavaScript in a new Office Add-In, how do I call the SDK if it's built on the .Net Framework? (I need to add reference to DocumentFormat.OpenXml and WindowsBase in a project.) Is there a bridge of some kind between my JavaScript code and those .Net libraries? Do I need to do something similar whereby I need to make REST calls to C# code like this - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/migrate-vsto-to-office-add-in-shared-code-library-tutorial ?